# Make inline-block paragraph element take all remaining space of a parent div

Tags: html, css

I have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Bhr4Q/

Now, I want `p` element to take the remaining width of the `div` element. But I need to do it dynamically (no fixed values), because this `span` element might not be in there, so then I want `p` element to take all available space. How can I do it?

Comment: @Diodeus: If I disable inline-block in both elements, then `span` goes up and `p` goes down. And I need them to be in the same line.

Comment: Can you put in some sample HTML of your different cases?

Comment: @ajp15243: There are two cases: `span` takes what it needs to take (this may be fixed widht), and `p` takes the rest available width, and the second case is, that `span` is not in there, and then `p` takes all the width.

Comment: If there is a possibility of the span not being there at all in your markup, then this isn't something you can do with HTML or CSS (I don't think, and if you can, then you shouldn't).  You will have to use javascript to check if the span is there or not, then apply a width to your p tag.

Comment: @Jerreck: times when we had to use javascript instead of css are far beyond us. :) But thanks for the input.

Comment: @Jerreck I used to think that kind of thing needed JS as well. Then I discovered `display: table`, and that it's [supported in IE8](http://caniuse.com/css-table).

Comment: @ajp15243 Ah, I misread your answer.  I thought you were using table markup, not display: table.  Seems kind of grey as far SoC goes, but hey it works :)

Comment: @Jerreck It's certainly harder to find a good argument to make it still satisfy SoC, but I think if you carefully think through it all it ends up working out. And yes, it works great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When i see "remaining space" i immediately think of the table-tayout:

```
div {
    display: table;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
span {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: blue;
}
p {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Where the remaining space is calculeted with:

```
.fullWidth {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Yes, tables are **still** awesome.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bhr4Q/6/)

*Note that i did not use `display: inline-block;` as we want to let the content fill the whole table-cell.*

Comment: It may be awesome, but when I have a project that has already been running, modifying it like that is a pain in the ass. ;)

Comment: Unless the content is tabular data, it'd be best to stick with non-`<table>` and semantically correct markup, and use the `display` CSS property's values of `table`, `table-cell`, `table-row`, etc. for table-like layouts.

Comment: @nkmol: Damn tables... But yeah, that does the job, thank you! :)

Comment: Glad i could help :) One love with the tables.

Comment: @ojek Note that you can also use the [`table-layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) values of `auto` to let the browser auto-size them, or `fixed` to make all cells have equally-computed widths. Also, it's OK to use table display rules in your CSS, since it still satisfies [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) (i.e. the HTML doesn't use `<table>` because it shouldn't care about non-tabular content layout, and the CSS dictates the table-like layout because CSS is responsible for layout).

Comment: @ajp15243 I'm sorry i did not read your comment yesterday. I don't understand the point of css table vs html table. I mean, don't they act the same? I would think HTML tables are more right because you will not edit the DOM display but stay with the standard. Could you provide more information about this? Thanks!

Comment: @nkmol If you use `<table>` in your markup, you are saying that the content in the table is "tabular data" that needs strict layout in rows and columns, and makes the HTML dictate the layout and presentation. This is fine if your content is data that strictly needs that layout. Alternatively, having non-tabular content should be put into standard content containers (e.g. `<div>` or `<section>`), where the HTML does *not* dictate layout, and you leave it up to the CSS to dictate layout and presentation rules (e.g. `display:table`). It comes down to responsibilities between HTML and CSS.

Comment: @nkmol Also, there's nothing "non-standard" about dictating table layouts in CSS. It's in the CSS spec for a reason.

Comment: I do agree with the "tabular data" as some screen readers will search for the HTML table elements. I did some test on the css-table and it seems less strictly. Where you can't use a div around a HTML `<tr>` you can actually do this with `display: table-row;` on a div. Thanks for your information! You really helped to get a clear view on HTML tables vs Css tables :)

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds like the `span` is somehow a part of the `p`? So you want to nest the `span` inside of `p` and apply `width:100%` to `p`

http://jsfiddle.net/Bhr4Q/3/

Comment: Well in that case you want to use display: table & table-cell on the relevant properties to create a table-like layout.